# Why pkill return -9?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pkill

I want to run command `pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'` in python3 use `subprocess.run`,  but I do not know why `returncode=-9`, can anyone explain this?

```
>>> subprocess.run("pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'", shell=True)
CompletedProcess(args="pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'", returncode=-9)
```

When I run the same command in bash shell, the return code is 0:

```
$ pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'
$ echo $?
0
```

**Run command in bash shell:**

```
root@w-test01:/home/renyuntao# ps -ef | grep -E 'java.*7104' | grep -v grep
root     127147      1 99 11:37 pts/1    00:00:13 java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx10240m -jar ./aichemy.jar --server.port=7104 --spring.profiles.active=test01_use
root@w-test01:/home/renyuntao# pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'
root@w-test01:/home/renyuntao# echo $?
0
```

**Run command use `subprocess.run`:**

```
root@w-test01:/home/renyuntao# ps -ef | grep -E 'java.*7104' | grep -v grep
root     128644      1 99 11:38 pts/1    00:00:22 java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Xmx10240m -jar ./aichemy.jar --server.port=7104 --spring.profiles.active=test01_use
root@w-test01:/home/renyuntao# python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Apr 16 2020, 17:47:17) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run("pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'", shell=True)
CompletedProcess(args="pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'", returncode=-9)
```

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for `pkill`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have read the man page of pkill, but not found useful thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/217726/joseph-sible-reinstate-monica) answer the question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/586748/143692):

> When you use `subprocess.run` with `shell=True`, Python starts a shell
>   process that in turn starts your process. This means that it executes
>   `sh -c "pkill -9 -f 'java.*7104'"`. The `pkill` process only has
>   special protections to avoid matching itself, not to avoid matching
>   its parent process. You need to adjust your regex to not match itself.
>   Putting a `^` before `java` is probably the easiest way to do that,
>   like this:
>
> ```
> subprocess.run("pkill -9 -f '^java.*7104'", shell=True)
> ```